# input type=date then datepicker Icon is not appearing on Firefox

Tags: html, datepicker, razor-pages, bootstrap-datepicker

On Firefox, I'm facing an issue, that is datepicker icon is not appearing in the textbox where as it is appearing on Chrome and Edge.
Below is the line of code and screenshots please check and let me know what are the ways to show on firefox

`<input type="date" required="required" class="formInput">`

[on chrome icon appears as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7lDU.png)

[on Edge icon appears as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haYas.png)

*[on Firefox icon disappears as in this image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVP72.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm able to resolve datepicker icon disappear in input textbox when we use input type="date". It works in Chrome, Firefox, Edge.
Below are the css I have used and applied those on divs

```cs
 .cal-wrp {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
 }

.btnCal-wrp {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.btnCal-click {
    border: 0.0625rem solid #cfd0d3;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

    .btnCal-click::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
        right: -10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 78px;
        height: 40px;
        color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .btnCal-click::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

    .btnCal-click::-webkit-clear-button {
        margin-right: 75px;
    }

.btnCal {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Calendar textbox code:

```html
<div class="cal-wrp">
   <div class="btnCal-wrp">
        <input class="btnCal-click" type="date" required>
   </div>
   <button class="btnCal"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work in the latest Firefox on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The input UI depends on the browser [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

You could implement a custom design (so it will always appear the same in all browsers) using jQuery. [Like here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Bootstrap-DatePicker-with-Calendar-Icon-Image.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The solution which you provided is good enough however I will try on my application and get back to you.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow @angelo, Normally, It would have been better if you had posted this as a comment because answers must be much more specific and detailed in this website and do not worry about reaching a lot of people the user who asks the question can upvote your comment, too.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't do that but, Here is how I would go about it:

The input outside the div is for other browsers. The one inside the div is for firefox. I use JS to detect the browser and act accordingly, hiding each.

Note that you will need to download a calendar icon and for your img src.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="firefox" style="border: 1px solid #DDD; width:max-content;">

        <input style="border: none;" type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22" min="2018-01-01"
            max="2018-12-31">
        <img src="calendar.png" style="width:15px; padding:10px 15px 0px 0px" />
    </div>

    <input class="anotherBrowser" style="border: none;" type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22"
        min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">


    <script>
        // Detect Firefox 1.0+
        var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

        //Hide 
        if (isFirefox) {

            document.querySelector(".anotherBrowser").style.display = "none";

        } else {
            document.querySelector(".firefox").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, this looks fine to manage on firebox but how can I show Calendar when user click on the calendar icon?